# Regular Expression to match hex string

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with PHP regex to match sub string in main string, but with some conditions

Sub string should:

1. String should have 7 consecutive bytes with at most (3 null bytes) '000000' in it and not a single `??` in it

Like for eg:

1. Input String: `4455330000002211223311223377885233`

   Match: `22112233112233`
2. Input String: `441553300000022`

   Match: None (Because it has 3 null bytes in it)
3. Input String : `112233000000005511220011`

   Match: None (Because it has 3 null bytes in it)
4. Input String : `11??0000002255`

   Match: None (Because it has 3 null bytes in it and having `??` in it)
5. Input String: `426F6D650000010001020000`

   Match: `426F6D650000010001020` (Because it has at most 3 null bytes in it and 7 consecutive non-null bytes
6. Input String: `426F6D650000010001000000`

   Match: None (Because not having 7 consecutive non-null bytes)

What is a good regex to match these correctly?

Comment: I recommend you download and use Expresso from Ultrapico. It allows you to design and test regular expressions. Life has been much easier since it was suggested to me. :)

Comment: @enhzflep thanks for tool suggestion i will try that.

Comment: Can the sub-string start with a null byte ?

Comment: The substring in case 5 has more than 7 bytes, do you want to find all substrings not starting with a null byte and as long as possible but not having 3 consecutive null bytes or `??` ?

Comment: @Sniffer yes sub-string can start with a null byte

Comment: @Sniffer '00000' are not counted in 7 consecutive  byte.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this regex:

```
preg_match("/^[a-f0-9]{1,}$/is",$str)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not saying it is the best solution**, but things like that can also be done without REGEXPs, just in case it could help you :

```
$str = explode ('??', $string);
if (count ($str) > 1) // It includes at least one '??'

$str = explode ('00', $string);
if (count ($str) > 4) // It includes more than 3 times the '00' pattern

foreach ($str as $sub_string) {
    if (count ($sub_string > 13)) // One of the sub_string between the '00' patterns contains 7 bytes as wanted
}
```

If you've to get back to your code later on, it becomes easier to maintain.

Comment: Seriously that i have think of that but its getting complicated to keep logic so that i move toward the regex but sure i will try this too thanks